# How to approach dynamically retrieving data based on different account numbers?

Tags: groovy, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-5.0

The situation I have is that I'll have multiple account numbers as my test data and when searching for their account number, it'll call multiple APIs concurrently.

Each account number will have different sets of information to populate. For example, let's say there a section for "loan account numbers", "debit card account numbers", "balance summary", and so forth.

Some accounts may have this information and may not. I was curious if I should use the if controller or create a groovy script to call it concurrently if it is present.

I don't think that makes sense when I think about it, because I assume using the If Controller would call it sequentially unless I'm wrong (new to JMeter please correct me if I'm wrong),but another approach I'm thinking is to just call all the APIs and whatever is returned will come and populate it since it may just be doing that anyways.

Let me know if I'm thinking of the correct approach or what I should be doing

Answer (score 1):

If the data cannot be [correlated](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) (extracted from the previous response) then you need to [parameterize](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-parameterization) it

Normally people put their test data into CSV files and read it using [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) and if certain "account" doesn't have load or debit card - just leave that field blank in CSV.

Test data can be generated once before you run the test or it could be populated dynamically on the fly, for example from the database somewhere in [setUp Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group) using [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler

Comment: Makes sense! So in this case I would have to look at each account number manually and see which ones have certain accounts. Should I still just call all the APIs that are happening at once and see what it returns? What I mean is say I have an account that has a loan account but not a credit card account. Would I still run the request to see if it has a loan account anyways?